# loop np.load until file-index exceeds index of available files

Tags: python, numpy, file-io, loading

I wish to read in all files from a folder using np.load without specifying the total number of files in advance. Currently, after a few loops the index will run out of the range of available files, and the code will terminate.

```
    index = 0
    while True:

        a = np.load(file=filepath + 'c_l' + pc_output_layer + '_s0_p' + str(index) + '.npy')
        layer = np.append(layer, a)
        index += 1
```

How can I keep loading until an error occurs and then continue running the rest of the script? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could catch the exception and break out of the loop that way, but a more 'pythonic' way would be to loop over the filenames themselves, rather than using an index.

The `glob` library allows you to find files matching a given pattern and return a list you can then iterate over.

E.g.:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob(filepath + 'c_l*.npy')

for f in files:
    a = np.load(file=f)
    layer = np.append(layer, a)
```

You could also simplify it further by creating the layers directly using a list comprehension.

Comment: Always in favor of more pythonic ways. Thanks!